# What does NSPOSIXErrorDomain mean (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, ios4

I am trying to use the ASIHTTPRequest libraries to simulate a form post and gather the resulting cookies; however, when I am running the post, I get an error.  I have traced through the request and narrowed it down to a NSPOSIXErrorDomain error.  The site I am trying to connect too is an HTTPS:  site and this error makes me think it has something to do with that.  Does anyone have any helpful insight they would be willing to share with this iOS rookie?  Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE:  I traced it erroring with code 54.  Not really sure what that means.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code and a stack trace?

Comment: Soved:  Developed a different workaround.  Still don't know what was causing this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved:  Developed a different workaround.  Still don't know what was causing this.